# How to make relative path to database in app.config using SQLite/entity framework

Tags: sqlite, app-config, relative-path

I want to be able to use a relative path to use a SQLite DB on more than 1 pc. 
the connectionstring in the app.config looks like this now:

```
<add name="DBPersonEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string='data source=&quot;C:\Users\Dreeze\Documents\Test DB2\DBPerson.s3db&quot;'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The DB file is in the same folder as the app... i would like to make the path relative so it refers to the apps folder. Can anyone help me change this connectionstring?

Answer (score 2):

Use this  connectionString

```
<add name="DWContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|DBPerson.s3db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
```

Then set DataDirectory path on your code before initializing Context objext.

```
string executable = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string path = (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(executable));
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path);
```

Comment: This worked great for me, why is this not the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the data directory substitution string:

```
provider connection string='data source=&quot;|DataDirectory|DBPerson.s3db&quot;'
```

Comment: Hi! Same question, but I could not make your answer work. Nor by inserting an extra slash between `|DataDirectory|` and the database name: `|DataDirectory|\DBPerson.s3db`. My connection string looks like this: `connectionString="data source=&quot;N:\Long path do my DB\MyDB.db3&quot;"` (note the absence of the `'` character). Thanks for the help!